# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException on Kitkat

Tags: android, android-drawable

While testing my app on API Level 19 KitKat device, I'm getting an error:

`Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0200ca`

on this line:

`seasonPhoto.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier(seasonInfo.get(0),
                "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName()));`

Everything works fine on Lollipop and up. Whats wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to use vector drawable?

Comment: @MaximOstrovidov not, its a picture

Comment: Check that you don't have the image in folder drawable for version 21 (in my case I had an image with text "(v21)" next to it. Make sure you don't have it.

Comment: @PiotrSagalara howdo we make that happen?